# Scale out SignalR without Redis for a high-messaging traffic Web app

Tags: asp.net, push-notification, real-time, signalr

In [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-502) on channel9.mmsdn.com about SignalR, the lecturer does not recommend using Redis for applications that needs to deliver a very high amount of concurrent messages. He suggested other three theoratical alternatives but without any implementation guide. I want to how can I scale out Signalr on commudity machines **on Amazon Web Services** and/or whether there is already a ready open source solution available.

[From asp.net:](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr)

> Using a backplane, the maximum message throughput is lower than it is
>   when clients talk directly to a single server node. That's because the
>   backplane forwards every message to every node, so the backplane can
>   become a bottleneck.

The lecturer explained in his lecture that Redis is can be the bottleneck. I am aware of the Windows Serve Service Bus on Windows Azure, but I intend to develop my project for AWS. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any update about this?

Comment: As for right now, I am looking into using Grantia Redis which is a scalable solution for redis alongside SignalR. However I am still blank regarding how to scale Signalr well without using a scalable Redis solution (cluster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the kind of traffic you will be using SignalR for, you might be able to use the Redis Soution. The MSDN Documentation states that the only solution where the Redis Server would be a serious issue is for online gaming but for push scenarios or chat applications, you should be fine.

[Scaleout in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr)